# HTC One M8 Network Name

Tags: wi-fi, 6.0-marshmallow, verizon, htc-one-m8, dhcp

I have a verizon HTC One M8 running Android 6.0.  I recently noticed that the network name that appears on my routers DHCP list for this device is "X2E GmbH".  I confirmed that this device is indeed my phone by comparing the MAC address, but I can find no information where this network name came from.

This seems awfully suspicious as the first result for X2E GmbH on google results with a German company which sells datalogging equipment. This is not a rooted phone, so it seems more likely that the network name change may have come from something malicious within my computer network.

Does the network name originate from my phone?  What should a default network name be?

Comment: Could you verify that Settings -> Developer Options -> Hostname (at the bottom normally) shows the same value? If you don't have dev options enabled, go to Settings -> Device Info and rapidly click the build number a few times. Then go back and check the developer options.

Comment: I can access the "Developer Options" menu, but I can not view the "Hostname" value.  From my research, it is because this is not a rooted phone. @ionree

Comment: Good point. At this point I think I can only do research myself, and you seem to have done plenty yourself. Here's just what I'm thinking: It seems to be impossible to change the hostname without root. This leaves two options: Something secretly backdoored root access, or something on your network is spoofing your device. The latter is more likely, yet also more scary. Try changing your WiFi password, restarting the router and only connecting with your phone.

Comment: One last thing: X2E GmbH seems to be a german company specializing in AUTOMOTIVE data logging, that probably being hours/distance driven by truck drivers etc. That makes this whole thing even weirder.

Comment: Install [Elixir 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bartat.android.elixir&hl=en) -> launch it -> go to Information -> Wi-Fi (under device tab) -> More information. Now, what do you see as Hostname?

Comment: Interesting, it appears you are right.  I assumed there was a bit of a translation issue and that Automotive ~ "Automated" and that BUS was in the sense of serial bus, not school bus.  Seems like a legit company despite the lackluster website design (also suspicious).

I concur that it couldn't have come from the phone.  I have checked my DHCP lease log and it shows what I expected to see for hostname: "android-xxxxxx..." @ionree

Comment: @Doug Ah, good call on the log. At least now we know where not to look. Are there other people using your WiFi or should it be just you? PS: Being fluent in German, I can assure you it's not a translation error.

Comment: Elixir 2 shows the hostname as expected: "android-xxxxx..." Time to start digging through my network @Firelord

Comment: @ionree All connected devices are accounted for.  My phone, which appears with the client name "X2E GmbH" in the DHCP list is the only device connected on the 5GHz band.  I can watch it disappear/reappear when i turn off/on the Wi-Fi on the phone

Comment: @Doug I'm trying to find out how feasible it is to kick all devices and gradually reconnect, as this would be the *fastest* way of locating the cause.

Comment: @ionree [LINK](http://www.pchelpforum.com/network-help/129333-chinese-company-information-client-name-router.html?posted=1#post1017111) It appears someone else had a similar occurrence.  We have the same router, and I did recently (3 weeks ago) update to Marshmallow.  I can't think of any logical reason as to why any sort of update would change the client name to an arbitrary company name (unless a clever programmer at google inserted a few fun lines of code)

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I have figured it out. I've learned quite a bit trying to figure this out, I don't have all the details but here is my Hypothesis:

I believe it is a bug in my router. The router performs a search on the IEEE Standards website to look up the manufacturer of each device based on the first three "octets" of the MAC address [WIKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address). The first three octets (xx:xx:xx) of the MAC address are unique to the manufacturer of the device. For me, my phone is HTC and so the first three octets for HTC are "50:2E:5C". The router must have a bug where it is doing a search and pulling the first manufacturer from the result and using that manufacturer name as the "Client Name". For instance, for my device: [Example](https://services13.ieee.org/RST/standards-ra-web/rest/assignments/download/?registry=MA-L&format=html&text=50-2e-5c) you'll notice the first hit is "X2E GmbH" which is what my phone is showing up as in my Client List. I don't know why only the android device seems to have the Client Name replaced by this result from the IEEE lookup and not other devices (as all the manufacturers are incorrect, but the client names are correct), but I think it is enough energy spent solving this mystery.

Comment: From my experience of messing with DHCP, normally clients communicate back and forth with the router a fair bit to prove their identity and whatnot. On android, this behavior is sometimes absent, which may contribute to what you're seeing.